# Adding a range on an enum field

Tags: enums, x++, dynamics-ax-2009, aot

I am trying to add a range (which I believe functions as a filter, right?) on an `Enum` field. This data source table is used in a `Web Report`.

This is what I do in the `init` method of the Web Report:

```
this.query().dataSourceTable(tablenum(SupplProduct)).addRange(fieldnum(SupplProduct, ShowOnReport)).value(QueryValue(NoYesCombo::Yes));
```

`ShowOnReport` is a field of type `NoYesCombo` `Enum`.

The Web Report crashes with this error:

```
Invalid range
```

I've managed to find quite a few examples on the web and this seems to be the proper way to do it so it supports all languages.

Any ideas ?

Could it be the properties of the field I'm trying to add a range on ?

Right underneath the line of code above, there is another similar line doing exactly the same, on another field:

```
//this is at the beginning of the init method...
AppointmentTable    activeAppoint = element.args().record().data();
;

this.query().dataSourceTable(tablenum(AppointmentTable)).addRange(fieldnum(AppointmentTable, AppointmentId)).value(queryValue(activeAppoint.AppointmentId));
```

This range works fine.

Thanks.

Comment: The syntax is correct, but I'm unsure of the `QueryValue` in your value expression. Have you attempted to run the command with `.value(NoYes::Yes)` (or `.value(NoYesCombo::Yes)`)?

Comment: this won't even compile since value() is expecting an str.

Comment: Could you compare value for activeAppoint.AppointmentId and NoYesCombo::Yes. Im sure, the compiler could not read enum value as per example. Try give a int value in your code : "...value(QueryValue(1));"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh crap. The Enterprise Portal server and its Business Connector was still at version RTM while the AOS server it connects on is RU8. After I patched the EP server to RU8, this works.

Thanks.